# Is there a way to map nested lists to objects with data coming from SQL views?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

So we have the following SQL view:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Name, p.Surname, c.ChildId, c.ParentId, c.ChildName, c.ChildSurname
FROM dbo.Parents p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Children c on c.ParentId = p.Id
```

And the following classes

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string SurName {get;set;}
    public List<Child> Children {get;set;}
}
public class Child
{
    public int ChildId {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
    public string ChildName {get;set;}
    public string ChildSurName {get;set;}
}
```

The project is .net core using entity framework and SQL Server 2016. I have tried JSON FOR and some deserialisation code but then I would want to decrease complexity since this requires inner select.

The Children list does not exist in the dbContext.

Is there a way with the current set up to map the children rows to the Children list of the parent?

Note: the actual code and SQL View is way more complex than presented here.

Comment: What do you mean by "The Children list does not exist in the dbContext."?

Comment: As in since it is owned by parent there is no list of children you can call with dbContext.Children to make any queries. I don’t think it’s relevant though since the whole thing comes from an sql view.